# Integration for php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a record of carriers and clients. When selecting a carrier on the customer screen, I need it to be automatically filled out the carrier's e-mail and telephone. The PHP file is returning a JSON correctly, but it is dropping in the error of jquery and not in success. I checked in Firefox's Firebug and the HTML tab of the console, where the GET requisition is reset.

```
<?php
include "Config/config_sistema.php";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transportadoras");
$menu_items = null;
while($ln = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
    $menu_items[] = $ln;
}
json_encode($menu_items);
?>
```

```
<script>
    $("body").on("change","#transportadoras",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var trigger=$(this);
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "buscaDadosTransportadora.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#telefone_transp").val(data.telefone);
                $("#email_transp").val(data.email);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Erro");
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

return in ajax

```
[{"ID":"5","Nome":"Vinicius","email":"viniciusbalbinot91@gmail.com","telefone":"32680018"},{"ID":"6","Nome":"teste","email":"teste@teste.com.br","telefone":"12345567"}]
```

Comment: One suggestion for dealing with JSON strings in jQuery is to use parseJSON(); http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ - this would be done inside of your success / fail functions in the AJAX call.

Comment: @AdamA please look at code and response.

Comment: select * should not be used in production systems.

Comment: It depends on error, which is not provided. But I had a trouble like this too, my PHP returned json (but in my case as string), but it was actually not a valid json. That was because I had PHP page in "UTF-8 with BOM". In normal editor, you will not see any difference (no extra chars), but in HEX there are 3 more invisible chars at the start of file. And the PHP returned theese 3 chars in the beginning of string with json, so on console, the output was fine, but `jQuery.parseJSON` always retuned an error, as theese characters are physically there in string, but you dont see them on any output.

Answer (score 0):

You response is array .

```
[{"ID":"5","Nome":"Vinicius","email":"viniciusbalbinot91@gmail.com","telefone":"32680018"},....]
```

you should loop through data.

```
 success: function (data) {
    $.each(data,function(user){ /* code ...*/});           
 }
```

If you want some current row select one row from mysql .

Comment: If I put $ ( "#telefone_transp "). val (data. Phone); $ ( "#email_transp "). val (data. email); After the $. Each should work?
Apparently that's just the problem?

Answer (score 0):

hope it can help u

php.php

```
$inp=$_POST["data"];  
$txt[0]=array("ID"=>"5","Nome"=>"Vinicius","email"=>"viniciusbalbinot91@gmail.com","telefone"=>"32680018");
$txt[1]=array("ID"=>"6","Nome"=>"teste","email"=>"teste@teste.com.br","telefone"=>"12345567");

for($c=0;$c<sizeof($txt);$c++)
{
    if($txt[$c]["ID"]==$inp)
    {echo json_encode($txt[$c]);}   
}
```

index.php

```
ID:<input id="txt" name="txt" type="text" />
<br><br>

Name:<input id="name" name="txt0" type="text" disabled="disabled"/><br>
Email:<input id="email" name="txt0" type="text" disabled="disabled"/><br>
Tel:<input id="tel" name="txt0" type="text" disabled="disabled"/><br>
```

js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("document").ready(function()
{
    $("#txt").keyup(function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url:"php.php",
            data:{data : $("#txt").val()}, 

            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#name").val(data.Nome);
                $("#email").val(data.email);
                $("#tel").val(data.telefone);
            },
            error: function () 
            {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }); 


    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: only when keyin id == id in array , it will return and show it